# How are operating systems related to docker images?

Tags: docker

A `docker info` command will generate metadata which says a few things about the current docker installation. One of the key-value pairs is `OSType`. I use a Windows 10 machine, yet the `OSType` is listed as `linux`. I am curious as to what this is and what it means for:

- Images
- Containers

Is the `OSType` a parameter that is global to both Images and Containers or does each newly generated image implement a different `OSType`?

Being primarily a Windows user, I would really love if I could simply make use of Windows as my primary OS for my Docker containers but I'm not sure if this is actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you can change the container type using the dockercli tool

```
Usage: DockerCli.exe [-SwitchDaemon] [-Version]
-Version: Show the Docker for Windows version information
-SwitchDaemon: Point the Docker CLI to either Linux containers or Windows containers
-SharedDrives: List the shared drives
```

about your first question, I've never used the windows version of docker, the only thing that I know is that you need to change the daemon to use linux or windows containers.